# Ghost platform not listening on windows 8?

Tags: node.js, windows-8, configuration, blogs, ghost-blog

I have the node.js installed. I typed the commands npm install --production
and npm start, in the directory where the blog files are. however, the output is merely: -

```
E:\Documents\Blog\ghost-0.4.0>npm start

> ghost@0.4.0 start E:\Documents\Blog\ghost-0.4.0
> node index

E:\Documents\Blog\ghost-0.4.0>
```

when it should be: -

```
E:\Documents\Blog\ghost-0.4.0>npm start

> ghost@0.4.0 start E:\Documents\Blog\ghost-0.4.0
> node index


E:\Documents\Blog\ghost-0.4.0>

Ghost is running
Listening on 127.0.0.1:2368
URL configures as http://my-ghost-blog.com
press CTRL+C to shut down.
```

How should i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It works exactly like this on Windows 7, I don't anticipate any differences in that between Windows 7 and 8, so this is rather odd.

You can start Ghost with node directly, maybe this will give an error message?

```
node index.js

C:\Projects\Ghost\ghost-0.4.1>node index.js
Ghost is running in development...
Listening on 127.0.0.1:2368
Url configured as: http://localhost:3000/blog
Ctrl+C to shut down
```